# Passing URL in a function

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to navigate to a website's page on the tap event.But I am not sure how to pass a link in the function.

Please suggest !!

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>My Header</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<ul data-role="listview" id="first">
    <li>Go Beyond 140 Characters</li>
</ul>   
</div>
</div>

 <script>
    $("#first").bind("tap", function(e) {
      <a href ="http://www.tricksfind.in/2014/09/twitlonger-go-beyond-140-characters-in.html"></a>
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
$("#first").bind("tap", function(e) {
  window.location.href = "http://www.tricksfind.in/2014/09/twitlonger-go-beyond-140-characters-in.html";
});
```

Hope it helps!